# What resources are there for learning Toki Pona?

Tags: vocabulary, grammar, online-learning, dictionary, constructed-languages

I recently started using Memrise to learn Toki Pona, because I find that language to be very interesting. Memrise is indeed useful regarding vocabulary, but I think it is not enough.

Are there other resources readily accessible on the Internet (or somewhere else, though preferably on the Internet) that I can use in order to improve both my reading and writing performance, such as chats, written grammars or dictionaries (specifically because there are a lot of fixed phrases in Toki Pona)?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 17):

This is what I used: [o kama sona e toki pona!](http://tokipona.net/tp/janpije/okamasona.php) (on Tokipona.net, unfortunately no longer available). It's one of the most popular courses, although there are a few points that differ from Sonja's recent book (for example, the use of "e" after "kepeken").

There's also [Toki Pona in 76 Lessons](https://jan-lope.github.io/Toki_Pona_lessons_English/) (in English, but also available in German), but it's been quite a while since I looked through that one; if I recall correctly there were some points not very thoroughly explained.

Also, if you want to practice or ask questions, there is a Toki Pona group on Facebook, and also one called "toki pona taso", where communication is carried on strictly in Toki Pona; no other languages allowed.

The official forum is at [forums.tokipona.org](http://forums.tokipona.org/); you can ask questions, post translations or original works, have boring grammatical discussions, whatever suits your fancy :-).

Answer (score 14):

I found this [112 page Toki Pona instructional booklet](http://rowa.giso.de/languages/toki-pona/english/toki-pona-lessons_en.pdf), covering everything from the alphabet to more advanced concepts, like words for thematic vocabulary or living things. It seems to be one of the most comprehensive guides out there, if you're really into learning Toki Pona. The [official Toki Pona website](http://tokipona.net/tp/default.aspx) also might be a useful resource, as it includes flash cards, lesson plans, a dictionary, and a comprehensive word list. If you need help with your Toki Pona pronunciation, you might want to look into [Forvo's Toki Pona pronunciation dictionary](http://forvo.com/languages/x-tp/). It doesn't include pronunciation for all words in the language, but it does provide 175 pronunciations by Toki Pona speakers for various words.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two English language Toki Pona video course on Youtube.

I'm pointing you here to the first video of both series:

- Learn toki pona in a fortnight: [Day 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qzWrG9iM9ac).
- 12 Days of sona pi toki pona Day One: [Reading and Whatnot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4L-dvvng4Zc).